# KeyStore getKey() returning null in Android

Tags: java, android, security, keystore

I'm using this code to store a key into a KeyStore in an Android App:

```
SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(key); // byte[] key
SecretKey skey = kf.generateSecret(keySpec);

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null, "ksPassword".toCharArray());

PasswordProtection pass = new PasswordProtection(
        "entryPassword".toCharArray());
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(skey);
ks.setEntry("keyAlias", skEntry, pass);

FileOutputStream fos = ctx.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("bs.keystore",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ks.store(fos, ksPassword);
fos.close();
```

Then, in another method, I use this code to retrieve the key I stored,

```
FileInputStream fis = ctx.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("bs.keystore");
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(fis, "ksPassword".toCharArray());
Key k = (SecretKey) ks.getKey(keyAlias, "entryPassword".toCharArray());
fis.close();
```

but the instruction `ks.getKey("keyAlias", "entryPassword".toCharArray())` returns null.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: what is PasswordProtection suposed to be? it's not an android class.

Comment: It is java.security.KeyStore.PasswordProtection. It implements java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I finally understood the problem...

I used the method to store more than a key in the keystore. Using the code `ks.load(null, "ksPassword".toCharArray());` the previous key was erased each time (because loading an empty keystore) and only the last one was stored on the keystore.

So the correct code is:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
try {
FileInputStream fis = ctx.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("bs.keystore");
ks.load(fis, ksPassword);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    ks.load(null, ksPassword);
}
```

The first time that the method is executed the file *bs.keystore* does not exist, so the code in the *catch* block is executed. Instead in the next calls the file exists and the new key is added to the keystore.