# Store/retrieve private key into android system keystore without using any file or sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, keystore

I want to store and retrieve private data(key) into android system keystore, but I have found everywhere file stream is created for temporary usage.

Below link works fine but they are using temp file.

[KeyStore getKey() returning null in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239474/keystore-getkey-returning-null-in-android)

But I want to save my data into android system keystore without using any file or shared preference.

How can it be done?

Thanks in Advance!